# How can I show a value from a table/Model using the form helper?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to show a list of checkboxes from a table, with the value of the checkbox being the table ID and the text being the label.  I want to do this using the form helper.

Example output:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">First Label</option>
  <option value="2">Second label</option>
  <option value="3">And the third</option>
</select>
```

My view looks like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('AddOnCategories.add_on_category_id', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
));
```

This produces:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

So, how would I amend the label?  The field name is `add_on_category_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the displayField of the Model to the column you want to show as the label, like showed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088196/cakephp-2-3-how-to-not-use-id-as-the-label-of-belongsto-select-options/16088394#16088394) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446524/cakephp-form-dropdown/16446744#16446744)

```
public $displayField = 'add_on_category_name';
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks.  Will accept answer shortly (need to leave it at least 10 minutes).